# Understanding the integral of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral, sequence-of-function

I have a integral with the following property:
$$ \forall n>0,\quad \int_X f_n(x) dx> 0  $$
I am trying to be able to say that:
$$ \int_X \hspace{.5em}\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \hspace{.5em}f_n(x)dx > 0  $$
Is it adequate to say:
$$\text{Since,  }\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \frac{1}{n}>0 \Rightarrow \int_X f_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)dx > 0 \Rightarrow  \int_X \hspace{.5em}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \hspace{.5em}f_{\frac{1}{n}}(x) dx> 0$$
Or is this incorrect?

Comment: Taking $\lim_{n \to 0} f_n(x)$ is definitely confusing, what do you mean? Maybe $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$? Then the statement is false though.

Comment: This is not true for scalars, so you can have $x_n \to x$ with $x_n >0$ but all you can conclude is that $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Man, you're right, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Hugo I am trying to take $\int_X \lim_{a\rightarrow 0} f(x,a)$. I suppose it is not a sequence of functions but an integral with a parameter.

Comment: Ok, so simply do not call the parameter $n$ then! The statement is not true in any case, you can say that $\int \lim_{a \to 0} f(x,a) \ dx \geq 0$.